# Save User Settings With IsolatedStorage in Silverlight 5 (vb)

Tags: silverlight-5.0, silverlight-oob

I want to save a value from a `TextBox`, an item of text from the `SelectedIndex` of a `ComboBox` and a `CheckBox` checked true or false. I then want to recall the saved settings with the `OnClick` from a button. I've had a go with the `TextBox` below but I get the following error statement: `KeyNotFoundException` was unhandled by user code. The given Key was not in the present dictionary?

Can anybody help me?

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)    Handles Button2.Click

    Dim Store As IsolatedStorageSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings

    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings(TextBox1.Text) = TextBox1
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    TextBox1 = (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings(TextBox1.Text))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ApplicationSettings works similar to a Hashtable. It requires a key to identify any setting you wish to store.

You can store your setting like this (air code):

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings("MyTextBoxKey") = TextBox1.Text
```

And you can retrieve your setting like this:

```
TextBox1.Text = CStr(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings("MyTextBoxKey"))
```

You can [read more about the ApplicationSettings on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221360%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your Help Kelly I should be able to work everything else out from your answer. Much appreciated